# Apache Spark Stderr and Stdout

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark-1.0.0 by connecting to a spark standalone cluster which has one master and two slaves. I ran wordcount.py by Spark-submit, actually it reads data from HDFS and also write the results into HDFS. So far everything is fine and the results will correctly be written into HDFS. But the thing makes me concern is that when I check Stdout for each worker, it is empty I dont know whether it is suppose to be empty? and I got following in stderr:

stderr log page for Some(app-20140704174955-0002)

```
Spark 
Executor Command: "java" "-cp" "::
/usr/local/spark-1.0.0/conf:
/usr/local/spark-1.0.0
/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.0.0-hadoop1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/conf" "
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" "-Xms512M" "-Xmx512M" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend
" "akka.tcp://spark@master:54477/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler" "0" "slave2" "1
" "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@slave2:41483/user/Worker" "app-20140704174955-0002"
========================================


14/07/04 17:50:14 ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: 
Driver Disassociated [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@slave2:33758] -> 
[akka.tcp://spark@master:54477] disassociated! Shutting down.
```

Comment: This is OK. Your driver program has done its job(word count) and disconnected.

Comment: What about Stdout, it's empty, does it make sense?

Answer (score 12):

Spark always writes everything, even INFO to stderr. People seem to do this to stop stdout buffering messages and causing less predictable logging. It's an acceptable practice when it's known that an application is never going to be used in bash scripting, so especially common for logging.

Comment: Thank you for the response--I have one more question which is about ReduceBykey.Actually, I want to know how many slave nodes will be involved by using this method? will it depend to the number of reducers that we set as the reduce tasks argument?

Comment: All nodes will be used provided you have more partitions than you have cores in total.  It's recommended you have at least 2-4 partitions per core.  If your data is already partitioned into a suitable number, there is no need to pass this param into the reduceByKey method.

Comment: @samthebest - are you saying that all Spark output goes to stderr? I did a simple "print()" inside my spark map function, and when i look at the logfiles from my slave machine, under work/app-<APPNUMBER>/0/, i see the printouts in stderr but not stdout. my stdout is empty. i find that strange - what's the point of having stdout if it's always empty?

Comment: @samthebest - is there a way to limit the size of the stderr, or expire the earlier messages ? I have a structured streaming job, and the stderr is getting filled up

Answer (score 7):

Try this in **log4j.properties** passed to Spark (or modify default configuration under Spark/conf)

```
# Log to stdout and stderr
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, stderr

# Send TRACE - INFO level to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMin=TRACE
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMax=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Send WARN or higher to stderr
log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.stderr.Target  =System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Change this to set Spark log level
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.util=ERROR
```

Also, the **progress bars** shown at INFO level are sent to stderr.

Disable with

```
spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=false
```